# Mean and variance of a product of the form $\prod_i(1+Z_i)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, recreational-mathematics

I'm working on something involving the following scenario: First fix $k\in\mathbf R$.

Let $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with finite mean and variance.

Also let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with
$$
X=k\prod_{i=1}^n(1+Z_i)\quad\text{and}\quad Y=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+kZ_i).
$$
I'm interested in the properties of the difference $D=X-Y$.

In particular, I'm looking for a way to express $\mathbf E(D)$ and $\text{Var}(D)$ in terms of $\mathbf E(X)$, $\mathbf E(Z_i)$, $\text{Var}(X)$, $\text{Var}(Z_i)$, and constants $k$ and $n$?

If not, what if we limit the scenario to the case when $\mathbf E(Z_i)=0$ and $Z_i\in[-1,1]$?

Any insight on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the fact that $(1+Z_i)_i$ are i.i.d, and so are $(1+kZ_i)_i$. The results are direct calculations I suppose.